# On Kolmogorov's Theorem In Time series theory and methods (1990)

Tags: self-study, references, stochastic-processes, cumulative-distribution-function

I am following *Time series theory and methods*, Brokwell and Davis (1990).

And theorem 1.2.1 called by the text Kolmogorov's Theorem is only stated but not proven. I will rewrite it here:

The probability distribution functions of a stochastic process $\{ F_t(), t  \in T \subset R \}$ are the distribution functions of some stochastic process if and only if for any $n \in \{ 1,2, ...\}, t = (t_1, ... , t_n  )' \in \mathcal{F}$ and $1 \le i \le n$,

$$\lim_{x_i \rightarrow \infty} F_t(x) = F_{t_{i}}(x_i)$$

where $t_i$ and $x_i$ are the $(n-1)$ component vectors obtained by deleting the $i^{th}$ component of t and x respectively.

where could I obtain a reference that proves this theorem? Was the proof omitted because it is a very long result?